# Get workflow name based on glue job run id

Tags: python, aws-lambda, workflow, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-glue

I have created a glue job (let's say job1) that will be used in multiple glue workflows using new triggers. I am trying to send an email notification in case the job1 fails. I am triggering aws lambda function based on failed cloudwatch event (from job1).

Below is the sample event response (event object in python):

```
{
    "account": "12345678",
    "detail": {
        "jobName": "job1",
        "jobRunId": "jr_12355686960",
        "message": "Exception: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)",
        "severity": "ERROR",
        "state": "FAILED"
    },
    "detail-type": "Glue Job State Change",
    "id": "fef2d09adasdasdasdasdas-d3-05f3a07adf70",
    "region": "us-east-1",
    "resources": [],
    "source": "aws.glue",
    "time": "2021-09-28T08:51:39Z",
    "version": "0"
}
```

The above event response is sent as an email through lambda function. Since the job1 is reused in multiple workflows, I would also like to include failed workflow name in the email. It seems there is no API to get workflow name based on the above details (for example, using job run id or job name). If there is any other approach (other than lambda function), you are welcome to comment.

Answer (score 0):

The SDK get_job() command (boto3: [get_job()](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/glue.html#Glue.Client.get_job) ) returns several attributes in the response, such as Name, Description and others. That may have what you want. Otherwise, another of the get_x or describe_x commands will probably contain the information you want.